# When can "tout" be used to mean "any"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

In expressions like *en tout cas* or *de toute façon*, *tout* is used to mean *any*. There are many other translations of *any* into French which would not use *tout*, and many contexts where *tout* does not mean *any*, but when **is** it okay to translate *any* as *tout* outside of fixed expressions like those mentioned?

The question was raised for me by another user mentioning the sentence *Toute vie est importante* – is that to say you can use *tout* to mean *any/each* with any generic noun?

For example, could I translate *Any friend is better than no friend* as *Tout ami est meilleur que pas d'amis* ? What about translating "*I think that any sandwich you eat, you will like*" as "*Je pense que tout sandwich que tu mangeras, tu l'aimeras*" ?

Comment: On ne peut pas utiliser *tout* (**un** sandwich) dans ton dernier exemple. J'utiliserais *quelque*  ou *n'importe quel*. « Quelque sandwich que tu manges, ça te plaira. » « N'importe quel sandwich...»

Comment: Right, I suspected *n'importe quel* was the correct choice there. So when is *tout* appropriate?

Comment: Uniquement quand *chaque* peut être utilisé à la place de *tout*... par exemple *à tout instant* ( = à chaque instant) "at any time". *En tout cas* ( = dans chaque cas) "at any rate". Can't think of a rule, if I do will write an answer.

Comment: Pour moi on peut parfaitement dire "Je pense que tout sandwich que tu mangeras, tu l'aimeras", même si j'utiliserais plus naturellement "n'importe quel". Exemple de contexte : deux personnes en prison qui se demandent ce qu'elles mangeront en sortant, l'une dit : "je mangerai un bon gros sandwich, avec du beurre et du saucisson, mais pas de salade, un peu de ketchup mais pas trop, et de préférence quelques cornichons, c'est exactement le genre de sandwichs que j'aime", et l'autre répond : "vu ce qu'on mange ici, tout sandwich que tu mangeras en sortant, tu l'aimeras, avec ou sans cornichons".

Comment: @Simon Déchamps : "n’importe quel" ou "quelque soit le"

Answer (score 3):

"any sandwich you eat, you will like" may also be translated by "tu aimeras tou**s** les sandwiches que tu mangeras"
that is very french and the meaning is very close.

The answer to your first question has been given by Laure : if you can switch **tout** and **chaque**, then **tout** means any. But then, you may also replace "tout" by "tous les" (all of them) and then it s plural and not singular.
ex : Tout corps plongé dans un liquide reçoit une poussée verticale de bas en haut" (beginning or Archimede's theorem)
is equal to 
"Tous les corps plongés dans un liquide reçoivent une poussée verticale de bas en haut".

In french tout is a powerful word, meaning everything (Je veux tout = i want it all, beauty, money, love, happiness...).
tout is useful when you want to express the universality of something, it's quite a "solennel" word.

Answer (score 0):

> There are many other translations of any into French which would not use tout,

```
"Any hope" → "Quelque espoir"
"Any volonteers?" → "Des volontaires ?"
"Any other choice" → N’importe quel autre choix.
```

Using "tout" to translate "any other choice" would lean to "Tout autre choix que celui-là" (heavy) or "Tout mais pas ça", "Tout sauf ça"… that may be valid only on some context…

```
"Any other questions?" → "D’autres questions ?"
```